# How to get ckeditor field value in modelform after submit in Django2.1?

Tags: python, ckeditor, modelform

1. I have installed ckeditor.
2. Placed "path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))," in urls.py
3. Placed "'ckeditor'," in INTALLED_APPS in settings.py
4. Placed

   ```
    ##  CKEDITOR CONFIGURATION ##
    ####################################
    CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

    CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/help/'
    CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

    CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
           'default': {
                 'toolbar': None,
                 'height':100,
                 'width':500,
            },
    }

   ###################################
   ```

   at the end of file in settings.py
5. models.py :

   ```
   from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
   from django.db import models
   class Help(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True) #models.TextField()
      class Meta:
          managed = False
          db_table = 'help'
      def __str__(self):
          return self.title
   ```
6. forms.py

   ```
   from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
   from django import forms
   class HelpForm(ModelForm):
       description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       class Meta:
           model = Help
           exclude = ('created_by', 'updated_by', 'created', 'updated')
   ```
7. help.html

   ```
   {% load i18n static widget_tweaks %}
   <form id="newFrm" method="post" novalidate>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.media }}

     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">description <span class="required">*</span></label>
          {% if form.title.errors %}
           {% render_field form.description class="form-control ckeditor error" placeholder="Description" %}
           <div class="error-msg show  form-error">
           {{ form.description.errors}}
           </div> 
           {% else %}
           {% render_field form.description class="form-control ckeditor" placeholder="Description" %}
           {% endif %} 
       </div>
     </div>
   ```

Question: I am not getting the POST value of description after form submit(in views.py). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Please put below script in your code.

```
    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() { 
                    CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement() });
    }
```

This code will update the raw data of ckeditor in to related textarea.
Now on submit the form, you will get the data in POST.